# How to graph $x|2x-1|-3$?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, absolute-value

I found it on an exam and it stumped me. Is it considered a function? Because I get the same outputs from $x = 0$; and $x = 1/2$

Comment: There are just a few cases to consider. Yes, since you are asked to graph it, it is $y=x|2x-1|-3$. by the way, **Welcome to the site !**

Comment: It is okay if two different inputs give you the same output. $f(x)=x^2$ outputs $1$ for both $x=1$ and $x=-1$, and I hope we can agree that $f$ is definitely a function. If one input gives you more than one output, however, then you are not working with a function.

Comment: you can get the same output for two different inputs and it will be a function but not when you get two outputs for the same inputs, it will not a function.

Comment: See here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x*abs(2*x-1)-3+x+frm+-5+to+5

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! So then, would it suffice only find the x and y intercepts, and the "vertex"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $|a|$ equals $a$ for $a \geq 0$, and $-a$ otherwise, we just have two cases to look at depending on what happens to the expression inside the absolute value, $2x-1$. We have that $$x|2x-1|-3 = \begin{cases} x(2x-1)-3 = 2x^2-x-3, &\mbox{ if }x\geq 1/2, \\ -x(2x-1)-3 = -2x^2+x-3, &\mbox{ if } x<1/2.\end{cases}$$Can you graph both parabolas and paste them together suitably?